# Society as a countable noun

Tags: countable-nouns

Macmillan Dictionary gives the following [example sentence](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/society) for the word "society" as a countable noun:
"Good writing still has a place in contemporary society."

I know "society" can be used both as a countable and uncountable noun but if it is used as a countable noun in this sentence, why is an indefinite article not required (i.e., in contemporary society)? Is it something to do with "contemporary"?

I hope anyone can help me with this question. Thank you!

Comment: In my view, the dictionary is wrong, and _society_ is not a countable noun in that example (though it can be in other contexts).

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary erred when giving that example for the use as a countable noun. The example clearly is using it in a general sense rather than as a concrete, countable noun. We can change the example to fit as a countable noun by either adding an article or by making 'society' plural. 
"Good writing still has a place in contemporary societies."
"Good writing still has a place in a contemporary society."
As we can see, this changes the meaning. The word 'contemporary' has nothing to do with the countability of 'society'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the article is omitted because society is being referred to in a generic, or general sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large variety of nouns that are countable and do not require an article when used.  [Here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv349.shtml)'s a resource which talks about some of them.  It is particularly true when they are used with prepositions.  Here are some common examples:

> I want to travel across the country by *car*.
>   There are too many innocent people who go to *prison*.
>   At *home*, people tend to let their guard down.